# Is there a native SVP alternative for linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, wine, video

SVP is a windows software application that calculates video frames in real time while a video is running in a player, making it run smoothly in 60 fps. It doesn't work in wine. Is there a linux alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a native Linux version of SVP: https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:Linux

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are interested in playing videos live without the need to process them first. In this case i can not really offer a solution but i want to point out that it is possible to enhance videos using SVP under linux using AviSynth and Wine.

http://jotschi.de/2015/08/12/svp-wine-linux.html

SVP also started a ingigogo campain in which they promote a linux version. I'm not sure whether this will include a player or not.

Comment: You should include the essential parts of the link here.

Comment: I asked specifically for a native alternative, though I'll definitly try this guide for wine. Since you mentioned it specifically I have to ask, is there a way to this not in real time by processing it before playing?